# how to read strings.xml as a file?

Tags: java, android

I tried to access strings.XML but I can't find the path of that.
I need to read `strings.XML` in Values folder as a file and access the content of that.how can I access that file and what is its path?

**Edit**

I used this before:

```java
 Field[] fields = R.string.class.getDeclaredFields(); // or Field[] fields = R.string.class.getFields();
    String str = "";
    for (int  i =0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        int resId = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(fields[i].getName(), "string", ctx.getPackageName());
        str += fields[i].getName() + " = ";
        if (resId != 0) {
            str += ctx.getResources().getString(resId);
        }
        str += "\n";
    }
```

but that return all strings of all libraries but I just need strings in strings.xml of my module.

I write Gradle code and I want some things like this but in java:

```
 def stringsFile = file("src/main/res/values/strings.xml")
def parsedProjectXml = (new XmlParser()).parse(stringsFile)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I found the solution
with Gradle function and right the moment of build make a copy of strings.XML into raw folder and after that parse that file.

Comment: nice! Can you post more insights? That would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

> I tried to access strings.xml but i can't find the path of that.

There is no path, because it is not a file on the device.

> how can I access that file

You can't. <strike>You *might* be able to get a parser on it via `getXml()` on a `Resources` object, though I have not tried this for a strings resource file.</strike>

> what is its path?

It does not have one.

Comment: @HassanYousefzadeh: Sorry, it just dawned on me that this will not work. `getXml()` may be able to work for other types of resources, but not those in `values/` and peers.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot read it from a path. you can define an array of strings as following:

in XML

```
   <string-array name="arrayName">
    <item>@string/String1</item>
    <item>@string/String2</item>
    <item>@string/String3</item>
    <item>@string/String4</item>
    <item>@string/String5</item>

</string-array>
```

In java:

You can retrieve the data as following :

```
       String[] stringsArray= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arrayName);

        for (int i = 0; i < stringsArray.length; i++)
        {

        }
```

Comment: that's simple.I want to parse the content of strings.xml.

Comment: @HassanYousefzadeh what do you mean by parse the content?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access strings.xml as a .xml file and just read it. The values from the resource files get reference in R.java file after android application is built. So you will have to access it using android internal API.
Below is a sample R.java file.

```
public final class R {  
    public static final class attr {  
    }  
    public static final class drawable {  
        public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020000;  
    }  
    public static final class id {  
        public static final int menu_settings=0x7f070000;  
    }  
    public static final class layout {  
        public static final int activity_main=0x7f030000;  
    }  
    public static final class menu {  
        public static final int activity_main=0x7f060000;  
    }  
    public static final class string {  
        public static final int app_name=0x7f040000;  
        public static final int hello_world=0x7f040001;  
        public static final int menu_settings=0x7f040002;  
    }  
    public static final class style {  

        public static final int AppBaseTheme=0x7f050000;  



        public static final int AppTheme=0x7f050001;  
    }  
}
```